# Importing two text files to compare as lists sequentially

Tags: python-3.7

Student trying to compare two .txt files of string "answers" from a multiple choice test a,c,d,b, etc. I've found some information on different parts of the problems I'm having and found a possible way to get the comparisons I want, but the guide was meant for in script strings and not pulling a list from a file.

For the import of the two files and comparing them, I'm basing my code on my textbook and this video here: [Video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV0CCt9W3_k)

I've got the code up and running, but for some reason I'm only getting 0.0% match when I want to a 100.0% match, at least for the two text files I'm using with identical answer lists.

```
import difflib

answer_sheet = "TestAnswerList.txt"
student_sheet = "StudentAnswerList.txt"
ans_list = open(answer_sheet).readlines()
stu_list = open(student_sheet).readlines()
sequence = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=ans_list, b=stu_list)
check_list = sequence.ratio()*100
check_list = round(check_list,1)
print(str(check_list) + "% match")
if check_list == 100:
    print('This grade is Plus Ultra!')
elif check_list >= 75:
    print('Good job, you pass!')
else:
    print('Please study harder for your next test.')

# not the crux of my issue, but will accept advice all the same
answer_sheet.close
student_sheet.close
```

If I add in the close statement at the end for both of the text files, then I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:/Users/jaret/Documents/Ashford U/CPT 200/Python Code/Wk 5 Int Assg
>   - Tester code.py", line 18, in 
>       answer_sheet.close AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: Include the error message.

Comment: Hi, The error I'm getting is 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jaret/Documents/Ashford U/CPT 200/Python Code/Wk 5 Int Assgmnt - Pt 1.py", line 11, in <module>
    if row[0] == ans[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I'm trying to create a way to compare the lists sequentially with a pass or fail system of >=15 passes.

Comment: Edit the error message into your question, and show a few rows from each text file too, so we know what we're dealing with.

Comment: You should really be using `with open(filename)` instead. `with` will close it at the end for you so you won't need `close`. Read about the `with` statement.

Comment: I have read up on the with statement and choose to go with out it. I was unsure if my either of the txt files would possible close before my script ended causing more headache. In any event, I figured out my issue. My syntax for opening the files were both incorrect. I've since changed that and now they both open and the files are seen as lists, get numerically compared by percentage matching, and then print out the lists for visual comparison. It then closes as it should. I will post my answer below.

Comment: +1 for using `with` - after you read the file content to a variable, you're done and won't have to do any garbage collection (`f.close()`). `with` does not introduce additional scope so you won't "loose" anything (e.g. variables you assigned to within the `with` statement).

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-look at how my files were being opened and realized that the syntax was for Python 2 not 3. I chose to go w/ basic open and later close to reduce any potential errors on my novice part.

```
import difflib

f1 = open('TestAnswerList.txt')
tst_ans = f1.readlines()
f2 = open('StudentAnswerList.txt')
stu_ans = f2.readlines()
sequence = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=stu_ans, b=tst_ans)
check_list = sequence.ratio()*100
check_list = round(check_list,1) 
print(str(check_list) + "% match") # Percentage correct
if check_list == 100:
    print('This grade is Plus Ultra!')
elif check_list >= 75:
    print('Good job, you pass!')
else:
    print('Please study harder for your next test.')
# Visual Answer match-up
print('Test Answers:   ', tst_ans)
print('Student Answers:', stu_ans)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: I edited to include the `with` statement and remove `close`.

Comment: By the way, I don't recommend using these opaque variable names and abbreviations like `stu_ans`. If you use real words then when you come back to it months later you won't have to guess what you meant.